# call back hell - returning the result using async javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

Function below print list of books when I call.

```
function getBooks () {
    db.find({ }, function (err, docs) {
      var async = require('async');
      async.map(docs, function(item, callback) {
          callback(null, docs); 

      }, function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
      })
    });
}

getBooks(); // prints a json array: [{book1},{book2},{book3}]
```

How the `getBooks()` function could return the result instead of printing them?
I mean something like below:

```
var books = getBooks();
console.log(books);
```

thanks.

Comment: You can't return from an async function. That's what async means.

Comment: @Quentin: then how can I get the result outside of the func? any other approach to use?

Comment: Use the Promise pattern.

Comment: @tokhi – Use a callback. (Or a promise, which is just an object that you can give callbacks to before or after the event fires).